# I have trouble finding tx hash

Tags: transactions

From

```
0x74e442b7ee73634cb55ce8d96d5ffa2b7a2f73ce
```

To

```
0x9BC98204e90F3c5b827D5f097808A765D8EE1121
```

Amount

```
0.01
```

Please help me to find tx hash.

Comment: Hi there. No transactions have been recorded between those two addresses. Where did you send the transaction from?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction doesn't exist. The address 0x74e442b7ee73634cb55ce8d96d5ffa2b7a2f73ce doesn't look like it's ever been used, either.